# Configuring Cisco 4500 series to send DHCP bind info to syslog server?

Tags: cisco, dhcp, syslog

I am working with a client who needs to be able to view centralized logs for dhcp binds from their multiple 4510's.

Is it possible to send a log of each DHCP binding to their syslog server?

Would this information be included in the usual message logging?

If yes to either, can you please direct me to the necessary documentation for configuring the switch to send logs of dhcp bindings to a syslog server?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I've definitely recommended a centralized dhcp server.. but not sure it's going to happen.

A bit of a workaround, if I were to configure an ip-helper on the 45000 to forward 67&68 to another server, would that prevent the original switch from continuing to function as a dhcp server? Would it forward all dhcp traffic, including acks from the switch itself?

Comment: I wouldn't mix a switch with an IOS DHCP server and helper addresses for the same VLAN. You shouldn't need to do anything but configure a helper address and remove the IOS DHCP configuration. Forwarding is handled, both ways, by the helper address configuration.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any facility for logging details of each binding.

You can log when high or low thresholds are met, and you can configure the SNMP server to send traps on some events, but I don't know of any way to log details of each binding.

This is where you would use central, full-featured DHCP server(s), instead of IOS DHCP servers. The switches could then simply use helper address(es) pointing to the central DHCP server(s) on each VLAN, so you interface configurations could be identical for this. You would just need to add a scope for each VLAN on the DHCP server(s).